# button hover color is not working

Tags: html, css

```css
#button {
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}

#button a{
    color: #15b097;
}

#button a:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" id="button">Create Account</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the first time it happen to me the button hover is not changing. It never happen to me I don't know what went wrong. Maybe there is particular went wrong I don't know. 
Hope I'm not confused you as I'm already confused here keeping changing the class name and didn't work. Only alignment is working. I did background-color as well as color.

Comment: Checkout my answer. Your button is with the `a` tag, so don't need to use `#button a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is with the `a tag`, so don't need to use `#button a`.

**Updated CSS:**

```
#button {
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    color: #15b097;
}

#button:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#button{
    color: #15b097;
}

#button:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

this should do

Answer (score 0):

Try this css i am sure that this is work properly:

```
#button {
    margin-top: 5%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    color: #15b097;
}

#button:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

> Just Change your css main id and it's reference perameter. Just Remove "a" in all css which gives you as reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong css  use bellow css

```
 a.btn-default:hover 
 {
    color: white;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use css as

```
    #button:hover {   
            color: white;
        } 
// or .btn:hover{ } or a.btn:hover{ } or a#button:hover{ }
```